# How can we integrate live dish TV ( no internet ) into an android app which can be run on an Android mini PC?

Tags: android, live-streaming, android-tv

I have developed an android app which can be installed on an Android mini PC to control the TV via internet. But, I also want to have live TV integrated into my android app so that the users have the flexibility of having live TV partly and run their promotional content in remaining part of the TV. 
What is the best way to integrate live dish TV (not from internet) which has a HDMI out along with my Android mini PC?

I am fine with using a separate server to stream the live dish TV into an URL locally and use that link in the app. If this is the only way to do it, then someone please elaborate how to stream live dish TV into an URL without any lag.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it. This Android mini pc only has an HDMI out. What this means is that the live TV is connected to a completely different source than the Android PC. How would the APC be able to change the image of something it is not even connected to?

If you absolutely have to do it, you need to modify the APC to ACCEPT an HDMI connection, take the stream through it after adding content, and THEN show it. Only question is: why would users do this?

Comment: I am fine with using a separate server to stream the live dish TV into an URL locally and use that link in the app. If this is the only way to do it, then someone please elaborate how to stream live dish TV into an URL without any lag.

Comment: It's virtually impossible to do it without any lag. TV alone has some lag.

Comment: You need a tuner which can tune the channels you want from Analog to Digital. Then use TIF to add new TV channels on your android tv. Whenever user tunes to your channel, you will get a callback and on that callback, you gotta provide the source for the channel and it will be played